# Eliminating redund terms

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, sympy

I am trying to symplify the number of parameters for some calculation using symmetry properties.

In this problem I am using the script below to generate all the linear equation needed.

```
from sympy import *
import sympy as sym
init_printing(use_latex='mathjax')
b1=sym.Array([[Rational(-1/2),sqrt(3)/2,0],[-sqrt(3)/2,Rational(-1/2),0],[0,0,1]])
Sigma=[]
for i in range(0,3):
  for j in range(0,3):
    for k in range(0,3):
        for l in range(0,3):
            y = symbols(('C_{%d%d%d%d}')%(i+1,j+1,k+1,l+1), commutative=True)
            args = []
            for m in range(0,3):
                for n in range(0,3):
                    for o in range(0,3):
                        for p in range(0,3):
                            x= symbols(('C_{%d%d%d%d}')%(m+1,n+1,o+1,p+1), commutative=True)
                            M=sym.Array([x])
                            Sigmatotal_tmp=tensorproduct(b1[m][i],b1[n][j],b1[o][k],b1[p][l],M)
                            args.append(Sigmatotal_tmp[0])
            Sigma.append(y-Add(*args))
solve(Sigma)
```

In my problem C_{mnop}=C_{opmn}=C_{nmop}=..... I thought to use the sum of the indexes to eliminate something like :

```
 if sum(m,n,o,p)= sum(n,o,p,m):
 keep m,n,o,p
```

but this requires to to write a lot of if statement, because I am planning to go up to 10 indexes.

is there a sneaky way?

Thanks!!

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what you want to do but you can use `sorted([m, n, o, p])` to get something that would be suitable for comparing them and if you make that into a `tuple` you can use it as a `dict/set` key. You can also use `itertools.permutations` to write the loop in a different way. Also `itertools.product` would help with your nested loops.

Comment: Sorry if the question is not clear. The code will generate for exemple C1112,C1121,C1211,C2111 which are all equivalent ; C1112=C1121=C1211=C2111 buy replacing C1121,C1211,C211 with C1112 this reduce greatly the amount of equation to be solved :)

Comment: Are you using `numpy`?  Remove the tags if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If symbols are going to compare the same based on some criteria -- like sum of indices? -- then use that criteria for the name and then you won't be creating redundant symbols. If the sum is what is important then

```
>>> m,n,o,p=1,2,3,4
>>> Symbol("C%s"%sum((m,n,o,p)))
C10
```

If it's not the sum that is the invariant but just any permutation of the digits that is used, then a binary encoding of the digits used would be better. For example, say you had subscripts 1, 2 and 5 out of a possible 10 values, 0 - 9:

```
>>> sub = (1,2,5)
>>> ['1' if i in sub else '0' for i in range(10)]
['0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0']
>>> int(''.join(_), 2)
400
>>> Symbol("C%s"%_)
C400
```

Then C400 could be the symbol name to represent that the subscripts were 1, 2 and 5. It doesn't matter if we put the numbers in little-endian or big-ending form.

Or simplest: just sort the indices (as Oscar suggested) and use them in the name:

```
>>> sub = (2, 1, 5)
>>> Symbol("C_{%s}" % ','.join(str(i) for i in sorted(sub)))
C_{1,2,5}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering again. The name is the criteria, using the sum is not the best way since, I will be loosing track of the variables. Is there a function that allows not to creat redundant symbols?